# Can I selectively apply the MudBlazor theme to a subset of pages/components?

Tags: css, themes, blazor-server-side, mudblazor, custom-sections

The [MudBlazor docs](https://mudblazor.com/getting-started/installation#manual-install-add-script-reference) instruct users to apply the following to either `index.html` or `_Layout.cshtml`/`_Host.cshtml`.

[image: MudBlazor Installation Docs]

---

My Question:

- Can I apply the MudBlazor theme to a **subset** of pages/components? And keep Bootstrap in place for the other pages/components?
- Razor Sections seems like a solution, but I haven't gotten them to work:

  - [From Steve Sanderson](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/28624#issuecomment-747485470).
  - [Blazor Sections NuGet package](https://github.com/inspgadget/BlazorSections).

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following, however disclaimer I have not tried this myself. I'm not sure if this result in conflicts between libraries and because you are loading two libraries there is very likely a performance penalty.

It is possible to configure different layouts for you blazor project.

Create a new layout with `MudBlazorLayout.razor`

Add `@layout MudBlazorLayout` on top of the pages that use mudblazor.

You can configure either Bootstrap or MudBlazor as default.

see [learn.microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/layouts?view=aspnetcore-7.0#apply-a-layout-to-a-component) for more details.